# Legacy operating system questions

Tags: windows

I need to know for a script I am writing for VMware. Is Windows 95 32-bit or 16-bit and is Windows 98 32-bit or 16-bit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both Windows 95 and Windows 98 are 32-bit, but they can run 16-bit applications and have a compatibility layer for 16-bit device drivers.

Comment: All Windows versions (excluding x86-64) are 16 bit compatible via [Virtual DOS machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_DOS_machine), right?

Answer (score 6):

Windows 95 and 98 were hybrid in that some drivers and applications included were actually 16-bit, although it had a 32-bit kernel. Recently, the same has happened with the 32-bit to 64-bit transition, where Apple released Leopard as a hybrid 32/64-bit OS, followed by the 64-bit Snow Leopard.

Comment: +1 for hybrid, which is closer to the truth.  Some OS elements were 16 bit, and a thunking layer provided a translation between 16 and 32 bit.  However, 32/64 bit OSes like Leopard or Linux don't do thunking, all of the os kernel is either 32 bit or 64 bit.

Comment: Though, for the purpose of VMWare, it's 32 bit.

Answer (score 3):

Both are 32-bit. Via [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_95):

> There were also major changes made at lower levels of the operating system, such as moving from a mainly 16-bit architecture to a pre-emptively multitasked 32-bit architecture.